# Pass "dynamic" variables between functions

Tags: python-2.7

I have my main script that I want to execute or load or import as a module. This file may include all my INPUT variables (a,b,c) which get changed later on (so is it better to put these variables in a extra script?). 
These variables get passed on to function one. Function one should add his results to the variables I've mentioned before, because Function two needs the variables I've mentioned in the beginning with the additional results from Function one.
Now I want to change the variables that I mentioned in the beginning (a,b,c) and do the same process again. I can't seem to figure out a way on how to update these variables "dynamically" as soon as I saved the file containing the variables. This means as soon as I type in sum(di) it's result should be based on the new values.
I started learning python couple weeks ago, so I'm grateful for every piece of code or suggestion you make.

one.py:

```
from one.tools.two import sum
from one.tools.two import avg
a=1
b=2
c=3

di={'INPUT':{
        'a':a,'b':b,'c':c},
    'OUTPUT':{}
                }
```

two.py

```
def sum(x):
    sum = x['INPUT']['a']+x['INPUT']['b']+x['INPUT']['c']
    x['OUTPUT']['sum']=sum
    return sum

def avg(x):
    avg = x['OUTPUT']['sum']/3
    x['OUTPUT']['avg']=avg
    return avg
```

Folder structure:

-Main Folder 'one': **init**.py, one.py

--Sub Folder 'tools':**init**.py, two.py

I run one.py

```
sum(di)
6
avg(di)
2
```

Now i open the file one and change the varables and save the file: a, b ,c = 4, 5, 6
But of course the saving process doesn't "update the variables in the function sum or avg:
What I want to get is:

```
sum(di)
15
avg(di)
5
```

Comment: There's not enough code here to understand what you're doing or what you want, but it sounds like you're using variables incorrectly. You normally don't want one variable passed around your entire program with the same lifetime as the runtime of the script.

Comment: Thanks for your comment alchemist... This isn't my actual code of course, but this example resembles the progress. As I said I'm not sure how to transelate what I'm trying to achieve. Everytime I run a function (for example sum) it should use the current variables, while the OUTPUT should be left alone as a temporary storage. Hope this makes it more clear... I added some stuff in the original post as well.

Comment: I _sort of_ get that, but that's why I say you're using variables wrong. You pass in variables to a function for a reason. Expecting the function to use the current variables over and over again means using global variables which will cause you all kinds of problems. It's not easy to understand the way data is flowing through your program from what you have posted, but it sounds like a design flaw. (This is very common with new programmers so don't get discouraged.)

Comment: I have another idea and hope you might comment on that. I will declare all my input variables in a function. The other function such as sum and avg will reload(variables) everytime, so they can use the updated variables. The output variables will be declared in a seperate file/function...

Comment: It's actually starting to sound like you're ready for a database. Normally if you have state you want to keep around like this, then as you obtain new values you would write them to a database, and your functions could load the new values out of the database when they're ready. Hope that helps.